# How to check if connection to SQL DB is reachable in java?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc

I have made an app in android that connects to a database with JDBC. I would like to check if the user has inserted the right settings. In other words if database is reachable. I am using this code:

```
       try {
            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
            connect = connectionHelper.connections();
            if (connect == null) {
                hasConnection = false;

            } else {
                hasConnection = true;
                connect.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            hasConnection = false;
        }
```

It works as long as wifi is turned off. In case mobile data is open, or connected to other networks it takes too long to respond. What could I do in order to make it more responsive?

Comment: Change the timeout period?

Comment: where? I do not have much experience in this area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Larnu, I looked at it and found it...

well you have to set the `setLoginTimeout` in `DriverManager` so something like this it will work:

```
    try {
        ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
        // wait for 4 seconds and then stop
        DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(4);
        connect = connectionHelper.connections();
        if (connect == null) {
            hasConnection = false;

        } else {
            hasConnection = true;
            connect.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        hasConnection = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform a clean connection, try following these steps. It helped me : 
https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/connect-android-to-mysql-database-tutorial.8339/